# A smart toggle class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a script to set different class name on a specific element…

Let's suppose the dom looks like this:

```
<body class='pre-existing-class-name'>
```

If I make

```
smartToogle('body', 'new-class');
// the dom should look like this
// <body class='pre-existing-class-name new-class'>
smartToogle('body', 'new-class-2');
// the dom should look like this
// <body class='pre-existing-class-name new-class-2'>
```

I did the following code but it does not work:

```
var smartToogle = function (element, newClassName) {
    var oldClassName;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.addClass(newClassName);
    if (oldClassName !== newClassName) {
        $element.removeClass(oldClassName);
    }
    oldClassName = newClassName;
};
```

Requirements:
1) I am using query
2) I would like to pass just one class name, the new one.

---

Solution:
The following code works but I do not like it because it uses global variable.
Any hint to fix it?

```
function myToggle(newClassName) {
    if (window.oldClassName) {
         $('body').toggleClass(window.oldClassName);
    }
    window.oldClassName = newClassName;
    $('body').toggleClass(newClassName);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the op wants to leave the original class name on the element and only add/remove the dynamically added ones?

Comment: yes you got the point, thanks @boz

Comment: Why didn`t use the .addClass() method? See here http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: my suggestion is storing original class in a data-class attribute on first toggle and then have it easily accessible for future "toggles"

Comment: he just needs `toggleClass()` http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ and @LorraineBernard why are you storing the original class anyways?

Comment: Here is a demonstration of `toggleClass()` :
http://jsfiddle.net/jdFYK/2/
 You dont need anything else to keep former class intact.

Comment: Just to make one point clear : if you call `smartToggle` twice (as in : `smartToggle('body', 'newClass'); smartToggle('body', 'newClass')` ), your `body` element will still have the `newClass` class. Is this what you expect ?

Comment: Some context would help. As has been pointed out `.toggleClass()` already behaves precisely like you are asking, so what are you trying to do that makes you think you need something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use data attribute for the element, that is accessible using

```
$(element).data(attrib_name)
```

Just a small change is required in your method

```
function myToggle(newClassName) {
    if (window.oldClassName) {
         $('body').toggleClass(window.oldClassName);
    }
    window.oldClassName = newClassName;
    $('body').toggleClass(newClassName);
}
```

can be replaced with

```
function myToggle(element, newClassName) {
    if ($(element).data('oldClassName')) {
         $(element).toggleClass($(element).data('oldClassName'));
    }
    $(element).data('oldClassName', newClassName)
    $(element).toggleClass(newClassName);
}
```

Hope this solves it for you.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

There is one thing you need to understand. 
If you want two different behaviors **you don't need 2 different classes for the change in behavior**.
One is enough, because you can change the behavior based on weither the class is **on** or **off**.

Let's say I want my element to have a red hover event in one way.
And want it to have a blue hover event the other way with CSS. 
Then this is the way to go:

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('.normal').each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });        
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BPBQN/2/)

Here we use a button to toggle all the divs and change their CSS behavior, looks easy now right?

However if you need to toggle **Javascript/jQuery events** as well this won't do. In that case you will need to use 3 other methods to manage this; `.on()`, `.off()`, and `.hasClass()`.

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('.normal').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).off('click');
        } else {
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                alert('You are clicking on an active div.');
            });
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });        
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/BPBQN/1/)

As you can see we have added an **if statement**. If the element has the `.active` class we turn `.off()` the `.click()`. And if there isn't an active class we turn the `.click()` `.on()`. Under the if statement we **always** toggle the `.active` class. So this doesn't have to be placed inside the if statement.

I hope this clears everything up for you, good luck!

---

**Old Answer:**

It is better to use `.toggleClass()` here.

Use a first class on the element for the default properties and a second like `.active` for example for the interaction.

Also, using a `.on('click', function(){})` bind will make you able to add interaction that will be bound instantly once the element is toggled.

Comment: `live` is deprecated (and was always a bad idea). Better to use `delegate` (or the hyper-overloaded `on`) and use a container closer to the elements you want to handle.

Comment: +1 thank for your response. Actually, I don't understand exactly what do you mean. Because the issue is about how to keep memory of the old class name.

Comment: you want 2 behaviors, like a switch on and off right? It's better to  toggle a class by itself than to change the class name completely.

Comment: sometimes there are more than two states to choose from (on/off) but something like (stateA/stateB/stateC...). posted a jQuery plugin for this use case..

Comment: I downvoted your answer : I think it is a bit off the point (doesn't answer the initial need), plus your examples on how to use `on/off` miss the fact that you can use them to *delegate* event handling to the parents - and thus avoid to manually replug the callbakcs on each change.

Comment: @LeGEC please make your own answer. I would like to learn from it and upvote it if you really have a better solution in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NCwmF/2/

I little jQuery plugin for that. Removes the current smart class (if any) and adds the new smart class. If called without parameter `className` the current smart class gets only removed.

```
$.fn.smartToggle = function (className) {

    var dataId = 'smartToggle';

    return this.each(function () {

        var $el = $(this);

        $el
            .removeClass($el.data(dataId) || '')
            .addClass(className)
            .data(dataId, className);
    });
};
```

​use it like every other jQuery method:

```
$('body').smartToggle('myClass');
```

Answer (score 2):

**NEW, SIMPLER ANSWER**
Works similar to before, with 2 additions: 1.) works if there is no class initially and 2.) works if other functions change the elements class in between calls. I also changed the function name so it doesn't interfere with jQuerys native toggleClass.

```
$.fn.fancyToggleClass = function(new_class) {
return this.each(function() {

    // get the last class this function added (if exists) or false (if not)
    var $this = $(this),
        toggled_class = $this.data('toggled-class') || false;       

    // if we dont have an original class, then set it based on current class
    if (toggled_class) {
        $this.removeClass(toggled_class);
    }

    // add new class and store as data, 
    // which we check for next time function is called
    $this.addClass(new_class).data('toggled-class', new_class);

    // alert the class, just as a check to make sure everything worked! 
    // remove this for production, or switch to console.log
    alert('element class: ' + $this.attr('class'));

});
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/facultymatt/xSvFC/3/

**OLD ANSWER**
I would suggest storing the original class in the elements data attribute. Then, your function can check if this data is set, and if so clear the elements class adding the original class from the elements data and also the new class you passed in the function.

If data is not set, the function will store the current class as data the first time it runs.

Check out this fiddle for a working example with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/facultymatt/xSvFC/

here is the code. It's a jquery function so it can be called on any element (and is chainable too!)

```
$.fn.toggleClass = function(new_class) {
    return this.each(function() {

        // cache selector for this
        $this = $(this);

        // get original class (if exists) or false (if not)
        var original_class = $this.data('original-class') || false;       

        // if we dont have an original class, then set it based on current class
        if (!original_class) {

            original_class = $this.attr('class');
            $this.data('original-class', original_class);

        // we do have an original class, so we know user is now trying to add class 
        // here we clear the class, add the original class, and add the new class           
        } else {

            // assign the original class, and new class, 
            // and a space to keep the classes from becoming one 
            $this.attr('class', original_class + ' ' + new_class);

        }

        // alert the class, just as a check to make sure everything worked! 
        // remove this for production, or switch to console.log
        alert('element class: ' + $this.attr('class'));

    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `new_class` is not added when no `original_class` was found in data (on first call). What if other classes are changed between `.toggleClass(...)` calls?

Comment: Good points, I updated the demo to handle these 2 scenerios http://jsfiddle.net/facultymatt/xSvFC/2/

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a global variable you can use data attribute as @ankur writes. Here is a working solution for your problem:

```
function myToggle(element, newClassName) { 
    if (!$(element).data('baseclassname')) { 
        $(element).data('baseclassname', $(element).attr('class')); 
    } 
    $(element)
        .attr('class', $(element).data('baseclassname'))
        .addClass(newClassName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do your job?

```
var smartToogle = function (element, preExistingClassName, newClassName) {
    $(element)[0].className = preExistingClassName + ' ' + newClassName;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `hasClass`. But you'll have to tell the function what *both* classes are:

```
function smartToggle(element, class1, class2) {
    var $element = $(element);

    if ($element.hasClass(class1)) {
        $element.removeClass(class1);
        $element.addClass(class2);
    }
    else {
        $element.removeClass(class2);
        $element.addClass(class1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. Actually I would like to pass to the function just the new class. It should remember the previous one.

Comment: @LorraineBernard: Then modify the above to remember it, perhaps using data to store the old one. It's quite straight-forward to do that. Seems fragile, though. Also, remember that elements don't have just one class, it's a space-delimited list. So you'd have to know how to identify which of the classes on the element you should remove. That's why you need to pass both class names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var smartToggle = function (element, newClassName) {
        var elementClasses = element.attr('class');

        element.addClass(newClassName);

        // check if there is more than one class on the element
        if(elementClasses .indexOf(' ') >= 0){
            var oldClassNames = elementClasses.split(" ");

            if (oldClassNames[oldClassNames.length - 1] !== newClassName) {
                element.removeClass(oldClassNames[oldClassNames.length - 1]);
            }
        }

    };

    smartToggle($('.test'), 'newclass');
    smartToggle($('.test'), 'newclass2');
});
```

**Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Q9A8N/** (look at the console to see what it is doing on each pass)

That should do what you want but as @T.J. Crowder said it is rather fragile and assumes that the class you want to remove is the last one on the element.

Comment: you are pretty close to the solution...actually it does not work if the orginal class name is formed by two names. here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/Q9A8N/1/

Comment: @LorraineBernard - your original requirements only mentioned one class. Try jsfiddle.net/nkxz4 and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question, I would go with [ankur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952301/86072)

As a follow-up to [Sem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12910256/86072), regarding the handling of jQuery events :

you can use the `on` function to handle any jquery event from a parent node, based on a live filter :

```
function myToggle(element, newClassName) {
    if ($(element).data('oldClassName')) {
         $(element).toggleClass($(element).data('oldClassName'));
    }
    $(element).data('oldClassName', newClassName);
    $(element).toggleClass(newClassName);
}

//event delegation : 'on' is called on the $('.divContainer') node, but we handle
//clicks on '.divItm' items, depending on their current class
$('.divContainer')
.on('click', '.divItm.plain', function(){ myToggle( this, 'red' ); })
.on('click', '.divItm.red', function(){ myToggle( this, 'blue' ); })
.on('click', '.divItm.blue', function(){ myToggle( this, 'plain' ); });

//initialize each item with the 'plain' class
myToggle( $('.divItm'), 'plain' );
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czTgd/2/).

You will note that the function called each time you click on an item depends on its "live" class, and that you don't need to manually enable/disable `click` handlers each time an item changes class.

You can learn more details from the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var smartToogle = function (element, newClass) {
  var $element = $(element),
      currentClass = $element.data('toggle-class');

  if (currentClass != newClass) $element.data('toggle-class',newClass).removeClass(currentClass || '');

  $element.toggleClass(newClass);
};
```

or the other variant:

```
$.fn.smartToogle = function (newClass) {
      currentClass = this.data('toggle-class');

  if (currentClass != newClass) this.data('toggle-class',newClass).removeClass(currentClass || '');

  this.toggleClass(newClass);
};
```

Comment: this will remove all classes from `element` on first call since `oldClass` will be undefined and `removeClass()` will remove all classes if called without arguments..

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation you'll have to keep the a reference to this instance of fancytoggle.

```
var fancytoggle = function(el, oldClass){
    // create a function scope so we'll have a reference to oldClass 
    return function(newClass) {
        // toggle the old class and the new class
        $(el).toggleClass(oldClass+ ' ' + newClass);
        // update the new class to be the old class
        oldClass = newClass;
    };
};
```

for your example the code would look something like.

```
var bodytoggle = fancytoggle('body', 'pre-existing-class-name');
bodytoggle('new-class');
// 'new-class' replaces 'pre-existing-class-name'
bodytoggle('new-class-2');
// 'new-class-2' replaces 'new-class'
```

to see it in action refer to http://jsfiddle.net/aaf2L/6/